# How to identify cached JSON statistics in Redis?

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, microservices

I am designing and creating a microservice in Typescript and NodeJS that must subscribe to some topics sent by IoT devices through MQTT, it must save the information in Redis, and after a while pass it to a SQL DB (MySQL), deleting the data from Redis. In this case, Redis acts as a cache, saving the statistics for a short period of time, so that, if necessary, it is faster to send those statistics to the front-end. Keep in mind that devices send data every ±1 minute, and that each device (and each client) has its unique ID.

This is an example of the statistics sent by a device:

```js
{
  "device_id": "00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046", 
  "timestamp": 1679052493,
  "ambient-temp": {"ambient-temp-1": 29.29,"ambient-temp-2": 29.29},
  "ambient-hum": {"ambient-hum-1": 29.29,"ambient-hum-2": 29.29 }
}
```

The problem is that Redis is a key-value DB by default. The value would be the JSON with the statistics, but what do I do with the key? I had thought of creating a "cache ID" that is the device ID + client ID + timestamp, because, this way, if a client has 2 devices, the data would not be joined. How would you do this? Would you use Hashing instead of key-value?

Comment: Did you check RedisTimeSeries?

Comment: Why do you need top include the clien_id in the key? isn't the device_id globally unique?

Comment: @GuyKorland Indeed it's unique but take into account that a device will send ~50k records using that device_id.

Comment: so again why do you need the `client ID`? it seems like it won't add anything on top of  `device_id+timestamp`